# Actualizar datos de base de datos sin actualizar pagina

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

tengo una duda:
Quiero actualizar los datos que se ven en mi web php que está conectada a una base de datos y que lo que cambie en la base de datos se actualice en la web sin actualizar.
Se que se hace con "Ajax" pero los unicos tutoriales que encontré son con formularios, y no se adaptarlo o no me sirve.

Acá dejo en lo que quiero que se aplique: Que se refresque lo de "partido1" sin actualizar la página (Todo esto está dentro de PHP)

```
    else if ($quediaes=="Wed" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12) {
        echo '<h3>Estás mirando: ' . $rows_dbpartidos['partido1'] . '</h3>';
    }
```

Comment: Es con ajax. y hace falta muchisima mas informacion para poder ayudarte. Que es lo que no entendes? no es solo para formularios, es para hacer las llamadas. De lo que sea...

Comment: No se que información se necesita, si no la pondría, mira, ahi edito y pongo lo que tengo

Comment: por ejemplo, adaptarlo a que? el tema es muy largo y complejo para un post. que cosas no entendiste o no pudiste averiguar?

Comment: Para que actualice el dato de partido1 de la base de datos

Comment: Revivo el tema ya que no encuentro solucion.

Comment: Se te pidio que aclararas mucho mejor tu pregunta. Tenes una respuesta que explica como traer datos por ajax. No sabemos nada de donde los queres obgener ni nada. Hace un [mcve] para q podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Quiero traer los daos desde una base de datos

Comment: ayudaría que incluyas el html generado de la página, que partes hay que actualizar, cada cuanto tiempo actualizar los datos. Si controlas la inserción también podes programar eventos con lo cual no se necesitaría un temporizador, en este caso incluir el php que actualiza los datos